# Prevent in app purchase exploits via Lucky Patcher from server side

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase

In our app, we do purchase via `com.android.billingclient` api, but as we get token, we send it to our server to verify, and only after the success we add credits to the user's account and then we consume the purchase in-app.

Now we're seeing users successfully patching their apps with Lucky Patcher and when our server tries to verify the purchase with google, it says that purchase is valid.

In our server we get something like this using nodejs iap lib:

```
{
  receipt: {
    purchaseTimeMillis: 'safdfs',
    purchaseState: 0,
    consumptionState: 0,
    developerPayload: '',
    orderId: 'sadfsdfsdf',
    purchaseType: 0,
    acknowledgementState: 0,
    kind: 'androidpublisher#productPurchase'
  },
  transactionId: 'sdfsdfsd',
  productId: 'sdfsdfds',
  purchaseDate: sdfsdf,
  expirationDate: null,
  platform: 'google'
}
```

Since we mostly check for `purchaseState`, it is returned as 0, which indicates success, yet the order itself was never actually paid for.

What would be the proper exploit prevention in this case?

Comment: Do you use code obfuscation in your release apk ?

Comment: Yes, we use obfuscation.